# (inc) & expenses (out) at each outlet are written not more than once a day, get a result set with the fields: point, date, income, expense

Tags: sql, sql-server

The firm has a few outlets that receive items for recycling. 
Each of the outlets receives funds to be paid to deliverers.

Information on received funds is registered in a table:

```
Income_o(point, date, inc)
```

The `primary key` is `(point, date)`,

thus receiption of money (inc) takes place not more than once a day (date column does not include time component of the date).

Information on payments to deliverers is registered in the table:

```
Outcome_o(point, date, out)
```

In this table the `primary key (point, date)`

also ensures bookkeeping of the funds distribution at each point not more than once a day.

In case incomes and expenses may occur more than once a day, another database schema is used.

Corresponding tables include code column as `primary key`:

```
Income(code, point, date, inc)
Outcome(code, point, date, out)
```

In this schema date column does not also include the day time.

Trying the following query, but shooting an error :(

```
select point, date, sum(inc) as Income, 
sum(out) as Outcome from (
  select point, date, inc from Income_o 
  union 
  select point, date, out from Outcome_o
) result group by point,date
```

Comment: Stop posting your homework

Comment: Trying the following query, but shooting an error :(

select point, date, sum(inc) as Income, sum(out) as Outcome from
(select point, date, inc from Income_o
union
select point, date, out from Outcome_o) result group by point,date

Comment: Please *edit* your question to include your attempt - you can then *format* your code by highlighting it and hitting the `{}` button. At the same time, you can tell us *what* the error message was. Those things usually include useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `UNION`, for a couple of reasons - one is that it uses the column names from the first query that forms part of the `UNION` - you're no longer able to distinguish between income and outcome. And secondly, it eliminates duplicates - so if you had a day when the same amount came in and went out, that would produce only a single row for the rest of your query to work with.

What you want instead is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select COALESCE(i.point,o.point) as point, COALESCE(i.date,o.date) as date,
       inc as Income, out as Outcome
from Income_o i
  full outer join
  Outcome_o o
    on
       i.point = o.point and
       i.date = o.date
```

For any particular `point` and `date` combination that exists in either table, this will produce an output row.

Comment: Dear Damien,
First of all it is still not producing correct result and second, why we are using COALESCE() here? because we are not performing any operation between i.point and o.point?

Comment: @learning - If you could edit some sample data, and the expected result into your question, I could test my query before answering. As it is "not producing correct result" doesn't give me **any** guidance on how I can go about correcting it. I'm using `COALESCE` because I don't know, for any particular row in the result set whether `i.point` might be `NULL` - Some rows will have data from both `i` and `o`, other rows will only have data from one side or the other. So I use `COALESCE` to make sure I get actual values rather than `NULL`s in the output.

Comment: Thanks Damien :) got the purpose of using COALESCE().

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CASE as follows:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN Income_o.point IS NULL
THEN Outcome_o.point
ELSE Income_o.point
END,
CASE
WHEN Income_o.date IS NULL
THEN Outcome_o.date
ELSE Income_o.date
END,
inc, out
FROM
Income_o FULL JOIN Outcome_o
ON Income_o.point = Outcome_o.point
AND Income_o.date = Outcome_o.date
```